# Create a 2D array using objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I retrieved the data below from firebase based on a query. 
I've tried to create a 2D array without success.

How can I do it?

```
Object {address: "6220 Lawson Dr, Haymarket, VA 20169", name: "Dave", petProfile: "A"}

Object {address: "2121 I St NW, Washington, DC 20052", name: "George W", petProfile: "A"}
```

Expected result:

```
[
 ["6220 Lawson Dr, Haymarket, VA 20169", "Dave", "A"],
 ["2121 I St NW, Washington, DC 20052", "George W", "A"]
]
```

My code:

```
var myArr = [];          
for (var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
    for (var j=0, len2=data[i].length; j<len2; j++) {
        var sub = data[i][j]; 
    }
}
 myArr.push(sub);
 console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Why are you creating a 2d array? Are you sure you couldn't use an array of objects?

Comment: You're right. I think an array of objects will work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move both objects into an array, iterate over each object with `Object.keys` and `Array#map` and return just the values.

```js
var obj1 = {address: "6220 Lawson Dr, Haymarket, VA 20169", name: "Dave", petProfile: "A"},
    obj2 = {address: "2121 I St NW, Washington, DC 20052", name: "George W", petProfile: "A"},
    arr = [obj1, obj2],
    res = arr.map(c => Object.keys(c).map(v => c[v]));
    
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***`.map()`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to simply do:

```
const myArr = data.map(i => [i.address, i.name, i.petProfile])
```

This will extract the addresses, names, and petProfiles from every element in `data` and put in in `myArray`.